# How to check if two random variables are independent without calculating their density functions?

Tags: probability

Let $D = \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \}$ and X,Y two random independent variables with joint density function:
$$f(x,y) = c e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\mathbb{1}_D(x,y)$$
I want to understand if X and Y are two independent random variables, **without** calculating $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$. 
However, I just know that method, any tips on how to approach this?

Comment: Intuitively: Knowing about $X$ tells you about $Y$ in this example, since $X,Y$ lie in the unit circle: $Y \leq \sqrt{1 - X^2}$.  So they are not independent.

Comment: @JairTaylor Do we know that both $X$ and $Y$ lie within the disk? Why can't I have $X=\frac{1}{2}$ and $Y=10$?

Comment: @JohnDouma No, the density function is $0$ outside the disk, so $X^2 + Y^2 \leq 1$ almost surely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and  $\mathbb P(a \le X \le b) > 0$ and $\mathbb P(c \le Y \le d) > 0$, then
$\mathbb P(a \le X \le b,\; c \le Y \le d) > 0$.